# Sign of the second order derivative in the sense of distributions at a point of discontinuity

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

Let $f:[a-1,1] \to \mathbb R_{+}$ such that $f(x)=\begin{cases} 1-(a-x)^2 &a-1 \lt x \leq a+1 \\ 0 & a+1 < x \leq 1 \end{cases}$

for some real $a<0$.

If I compute the first order derivative of $f\;$, I obtain $f^{\prime}(x)=\begin{cases} 2(a-x) &a-1 \lt x \leq a+1 \\ 0 & a+1 < x \leq 1 \end{cases} \quad$  which has a discontinuity of first kind at $x=a+1$.

I am interested in estimating **the sign of the second order derivative at $x=a+1$.** To this end, I tried to compute this derivative in the sense of distributions. If $\phi \in \mathcal C^1_c([a-1,1])$ then

$\begin{align} \frac{d}{dx} f^{\prime}(\phi)=-\int_{a-1}^{a+1} 2(a-x)\phi^{\prime}(x)\;dx&=2\phi(a+1)+2\int_{a-1}^{a+1} \phi(x)\;dx\\&=2\delta_{a+1}(\phi)+2\int_{a-1}^{a+1} \phi(x)\;dx \end{align}$

At this point, I got stuck! Are my computations correct? If yes, then what am I missing? I don't see which will the sign of the second derivative of $f$ be at $x=a+1$... Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is something wrong with this question. If the parameter _a_ can truly be any element of the reals then _a_=2 tells us information about _f_ only at a single point, and nowhere else. In particular, one cannot decide anything about its continuity or how much is lacking thereof.

Comment: @mmfrgmpds I see what you mean. My mistake. I re edited the question and I hope now it works well...

Comment: The integration bounds are inconsistent with the test function domain. It may be helpful to realize that

  _f" ~ -2*sgn(x-(a+1))^2_ ,

and that zero is neither positive nor negative.

Comment: What do you mean by the "sign of a distribution at a point"? Distributionally, the second derivative of $f$ is $-2\cdot \chi_{(a-1,a+1)} + 2\delta_{a+1}$. Of course we could say that the sign is positive because $\delta$ is a positive measure in this case.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, this is what I wanted to figure out. But what about the contribution of the sign of the term with the chatacteristic? Could you please explain in more details if possible how you calculated this $-2\cdot \chi_{(a-1,a+1)} + \delta_{a+1}$? It's been a long time since I used distribution theory and this calculation is not so clear at the moment. Thanks in advance

Comment: Differentiating a jump discontinuity gives "height of jump times Dirac". Here the jump has height $2$ (I initially forgot the factor $2$ on the $\delta$), since the left hand limit of $f'$ at $a+1$ is $-2$, and the right hand limit is $0$. Apart from the jump, $f'$ is classically differentiable, and the classical derivative makes up the remaining part of the distributional derivative.

Comment: @DanielFischer oh, yes! Your explanation is what I needed! Many many thanks!

Comment: In your computations, you have a sign error, it ought to be $$2\delta_{a+1}(\phi) - 2\int_{a-1}^{a+1} \phi(x)\,dx\,.$$ There are three minus signs, one from before the integral, one from differentiating $2(a-x)$, and one from the integration by parts. It's easier to avoid that sign error if you write $$\int_{a-1}^{a+1} 2(x-a)\phi'(x)\,dx\,.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer I missed this, you're right. One last thing. How do we know the ditsributional derivative is positive? Since there is the $-2\chi_{(a-1,a+1)}$ term?

Comment: Well, that's the thing, what does the "sign of a distribution (at a point)" mean? We can in some situations say we define the sign such and such, and that can make sense. But I don't think we can sensibly define it for all cases. Here is a situation somewhat at the boundary (still rather tame). Since $\{a+1\}$ is irrelevant for the regular part of the distribution but $\{a+1\}$ has positive measure for the Dirac part, it can be reasonable to say that $f''$ is positive at $a+1$. But one can also reasonably say that the sign at $a+1$ isn't defined.

Comment: @DanielFischer Hmm.. Is not that immediate why the sign at $a+1$ isn't defined but I need some time to think about it too. In any case, thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 1):

To find the distributional equivalent of $f''$, one calculates, say $\varphi\,' \in \mathcal{C^\infty_c([a-1,1])}$, and calculates the Schwartz bracket quantity,
$$
\begin{align}
\langle f'',\,\varphi'\rangle &= - \langle f',\,\varphi''\rangle \\
&= -\int\limits_{a-1}^1 f'(x)\,\varphi''(x)\;{\rm d} x \\
&= -2\int\limits_{a-1}^{a+1} (a-x)\,\varphi''(x)\;{\rm d} x -\int\limits_{a+1}^1 0\cdot\,\varphi''(x)\;{\rm d} x \\
&= -2\int\limits_{a-1}^{a+1} (a-x)\,\varphi''(x)\;{\rm d} x \\
&= -2a\int\limits_{a-1}^{a+1}\varphi''(x)\;{\rm d} x + 2\int\limits_{a-1}^{a+1} x\,\varphi''(x)\;{\rm d} x \\
&= 2\varphi'(a+1) - 2\varphi(a+1) \\
&= 2\langle(\delta_{a+1},\,\varphi'\rangle + 2\langle(h_{a+1},\,\varphi'\rangle \\
&= \langle f'',\,\varphi'\rangle.
\end{align}
$$
The above is true for all $\varphi'$ in the test function space, and so therefore one must conclude from the last two lines that,
$$
f'' \doteq 2\delta_{a+1} + 2h_{a+1},
$$
where the symbol $\doteq$ means "is equal in the sense of distributions", and $h(x)$ is the Heaviside function which is $1$ for $x > 0$ and $0$ for $x<0$. $\qquad\blacksquare$

Comment: In case it was not obvious, this implies that the"sign" of $f''$ at $x=a+1$ is positive because both $\delta$ is a positive linear functional, and $h(a+1)=\tfrac{1}{2}>0$. The value of the Heaviside function at its jump discontinuity can be viewed as either a fact from the Fourier transform of distributions or as the mean value of the disagreeing limits from each side $(1+0)/2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Although your calculations seem correct, I am a bit confused now. In the comment section, we agreed on a formula, that is $-2\cdot \chi_{(a-1,a+1)} + 2\delta_{a+1}$ and which should be equivalent to the one you concluded. Why is $h_{a+1}= -\chi_{(a-1,a+1)}$? Maybe is too late and my brain is burnt but I don't see it

Comment: Yes, it depends on what one means exactly by the definition of the characteristic function $\chi$. If this is the same as the box function with unit height and width $2a$, then $B(-a,a) = h(x+a) - h(x-a) = \chi[-a,a]$ ? For $x > -a$, $\chi = 1 - h(x-a) = h(a-x)$. One should double check  the signs, but I did not find an error in my proof yet if there is one.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You have $f'((a+1)^-) = -2$ and $f'((a+1)^+) = 0$ so $f'$ increases at $x=a+1$. Therefore the sign of $f''$ at $x=a+1$ is positive.